# Extracting properties of a hydra:class or members of a hydra:collection with heracles.ts

Tags: json-ld, hydra-core

I'm looking for guidance in working with `hydra:class` and `hydra:collection/hydra:member` object properties from responses gotten from a custom [Hydra](https://www.hydra-cg.com/) endpoint requested with the reference client in TypeScript, [Heracles.ts](https://github.com/HydraCG/Heracles.ts).

For example, consider the following JSON-LD response from my server:

```json
{
  "context": {...},
  "member": [
    {
      "@id": "example:2bfd5353-6842-48f7-9f8c-111474f57dfb",
      "@type": "schema:person",
      "label": "Person 1"
    },
    {
      "@id": "example:108d8384-a55a-4b21-8511-654fb3830d5f",
      "@type": "schema:person",
      "label": "Person 2"
    },
  ],
}
```

I can get this response and loop over it just fine with the following code:

```js
const data = await Client.getResource(
  "http://example.com/api/persons"
);
for (const person of data.members) {
  const iri = person.iri;
  const label = person.label; // How can I do this?
}
```

I could not figure out how to extract properties apart from the `iri` and `type` from the response. The documentation and use cases in the Hydra repository only talk about things like *do something with the* object (for example in the [Use Case Draft 4](https://github.com/HydraCG/cookbook/blob/master/drafts/4.obtaining-single-event.md)) without showing how to do it. I also couldn't find concrete examples in the tests and other source code in the repo.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Best,
Daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have asked the same question on the Heracles GitHub Repository and have gotten the [answer](https://github.com/HydraCG/Heracles.ts/issues/136#issuecomment-823587638) that accessors for content apart from the Hydra Metadata need to be implemented manually, similar to this:

```js
const data = await Client.getResource(
  "http://localhost:4000/persons"
);
const graph = await jsonld.expand(await data.json());
for (const person of data.members) {
  const personResource = graph["@graph"].find(_ => _["@id"] === person.iri);
  const label = personResource["http://some.uri/vocab#label][0]["@value"];
}
```

Source: alien-mcl on [GitHub](https://github.com/HydraCG/Heracles.ts/issues/136#issuecomment-823587638)